# How do I calculate averages after storing a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program to calculate averages. Everything works perfectly, except when the program tries to calculate the average. It seems like my input isnt being stored, therefore it calculates 0.0 as the averages. I am using Python IDLE on 3.6. Here is my code:

def main():

```
#variables holding the total number of wins per year

year1 = 0
year2 = 0
year3 = 0
year4 = 0
year5 = 0
average = year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5/5

#Introduction

print ("Enter number of wins when prompted")

#Ask user for win totals per year

year1 = (input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year2 = (input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year3 = (input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year4 = (input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year5 = (input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))

#calculate average

print ("Total average of wins over five years: ", average)
```

Here is the result after entering my values:

Enter number of wins when prompted

Please enter the number of wins for year one: 8

Please enter the number of wins for year one: 6

Please enter the number of wins for year one: 3

Please enter the number of wins for year one: 7

Please enter the number of wins for year one: 9

Total average of wins over five years:   0.0

Comment: You should consider the order of arithmetic operators and also the order of the statements

Comment: First of all  average = year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5/5 should be in the end before print ("Total average of wins over five years: ", average). Second it's wrong. `It should be average = (year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5)/5.0

Comment: You misunderstand what assignment does in programming. The program goes through each line in succession and executes it. Near the top of your code your formula for the average calculates the number 0 and stores it in the variable called `average`. This formula is not some kind of definition of `average`. If you change the values of the years, `average` will not change. Not until you set it to something else. In a nutshell, you need to calculate the average and store it in `average` only once you have all the year values. In addition, assigning all those years to be 0 is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compute the average after the variables have been assigned, also you need to convert the input to integers (int). Also as noted by @Denziloe and @Vage Egiazarian, you should consider the order of the arithmetic operations. Follow the code:

```
print ("Enter number of wins when prompted")

#Ask user for win totals per year

year1 = int(input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year2 = int(input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year3 = int(input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year4 = int(input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))
year5 = int(input("Please enter the number of wins for year one: "))

#calculate average

average = (year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5)/5
print ("Total average of wins over five years: ", average)
```

Comment: That's still an incorrect formula for the average. Note the order of operations.

Comment: average = year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5/5 is wrong . Should be average = (year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5)/5.0

Comment: Updated the answer with the fix

Comment: It would also be more concise to use a list instead of separate variables and collect input in a loop, maybe OP would benefit from it

Comment: You guys rock, thank you for being so helpful! I am 2 weeks into my first programming class in college so I don't know how to use loops just yet!

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's update is correct, you created the average too early.
Here's some updated code to help your learning:

```
print ("Enter number of wins when prompted")

#Ask user for win totals per year
wins_by_year = []
for year in range(5):
    wins_by_year.append(int(input("Please enter the number of wins for year {}: ".format(year+1))))

average = sum(wins_by_year)/len(wins_by_year)
print ("Total average of wins over five years: {}".format(average))
```